# How to run the login scenario before other scenarios

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I have two features

1. Login
2. Visit home page after login
3. Click a link on the home page

Visit home page after login

I have implemented the two features in two different files along with step definitions.

I would like implement the test so that Login feature is called before feature #2 and #3

I have heard about Before and After scenario hooks

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace SpecFlowUiAutomation
{
    [Binding]
    public class LoginHooks
    {
        [Before (Order =5)]
        public void LoginToTheSite(ScenarioContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[BeforeScenario] - Login to the site");
        }

        [After (Order =5)]
        public void LogoutOfTheSite(ScenarioContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[After Scenario] - Logout of the site");
        }
    }
}
```

If I am to implement a hook like this, it would seem I am duplicating the login feature in a hard coded fashion.

Is there a better way to build the dependency of the *login* feature for the other two features?

Comment: I am using Nunit. In Nunit the execution of test order is depend on alphabetic order. So I added tag like s1, s2, s3 ... before the scenario in feature file. And this works as expected. Not: this may not be the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that logging in is a prerequisite for many scenarios. In Gherkin, prerequisites are represented as `Given` steps. From a behavior standpoint, logging in is a crucially important step, and should be captured in your scenario. As such, you need a `Given` in your scenario that logs the user in.

```
Scenario: ...
    Given the user is logged in as "..."
    When I do the thing
    Then the result is correct
```

If you already do this, then you are doing it correctly. This minimal amount of "repetition" is considered acceptable, because of how important this step is to the scenario.

Logging in each time also ensures the user has a new session on the server, which can help guard against false failures or passes due to data that may be cached in the session from previous use cases.

Comment: usage of tag like @alreadyLoggedIn would have same effect? In which case I am not sure how parameterisation of user details would be fed in

Comment: Whether you use a tag or an explicit step, your scenario needs to know if the user is logged in. And you are also correct in saying that user details are difficult to simulate without steps specifically for setting up the user account in various forms.